# How to handle soft links in Perl

Tags: perl

Hi I am writing a Perl script to search for a file inside a specified directory, I used File::Find to do the same. But what happened was the folder which I was searching was pointing to a softlink, If I give the softlink path it was able to find the file correctly. But if I give the folder path it was saying file not found. I have also mentioned the script below. How to know that the folder/directory which we are searching is pointing to softlink or not. If it is pointing then how to get that softlink path to continue the search.

```
#!/pkg/qct/software/perl/5.22.0/bin/perl -w
##!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
#use warnings;
use File::Find;
my $gds_file_num;
my @gds_file;
our $dir = "/<path>/";
my @files_list;
use 5.010;

open( my $fh, '<', "data.txt") or die "Can't open data.txt: $!";


   # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find the file from given directory path 
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub find_file  {
  my $file_name = $_[0];
  my $dir_path = $_[1];
  my @result;

  undef @result;
  print "file=$file_name dir=$dir_path\n";
  find ( sub {
    return unless /$file_name$/;
    push @result, $File::Find::name;
  }, $dir_path );

  if(($result[0] ~~ undef)){
    print "[Warn] : File not exist : $file_name is not available under $dir_path\n";
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return $result[0];
  }
}


while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
  # chomp $line;
      if ( $line =~ /g0hd/ ) {
          print $line;
              }
        }      
      close $fh;
```

Comment: Have you tried `use Cwd 'abs_path';` and something like:  

`if ( -f $file && -l $file ) {
    print abs_path($file);
}`

Comment: When in doubt => perldoc. https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find#follow

Comment: @Stuart : I tried using whatever you have mentioned like this ,

Comment: @Stuart : Could you please help me with the same.

Comment: @Stuart: sub find_file { my $file_name = $_[0]; my $dir_path = $_[1]; my result; undef result; print "file=$file_name dir=$dir_path\n"; find ( sub { return unless /$file_name$/; if ( -f $file_name && -l $file_name ) { print "file_path is = $dir_path\n"; } push result, $File::Find::name; }, $dir_path ); I gave the abs_path as my$dir ,But the file is still not found....

Comment: Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Add 'follow => 1;' line before the 'push @result...' line.

Comment: Please follow recommendations that people give you here, and Cyxoi27 even gave you the link.  The package should be specifically told to "follow" symbolic links.

Comment: @zdim: Thanks for your kind reply...

Comment: You are welcome.  That wasn't meant to be stern or unfriendly, but rather informative -- sometimes you get everything you need in a skinny half-line comment. I've noticed that people with less experience here don't realize that and then often don't look carefully into comments, thus my note.

Comment: The question is OK and you may be missing only that one bit.  (Please let us know if that doesn't solve it.)

Comment: Tips: (1) Don't use `~~`. As attractive as it is, it comes with all kinds of issues and is certainly going to be substantially changed in future releases. (2) To empty an array do `@result = ();`.  You don't need `undef`, while it also implies new memory allocations once you use that array later.

Comment: find ( {wanted => \&process, follow => 1, bydepth =>1 }, $dir);

      sub process {
      # print "Enterning the $File::Find::name \n";
       my $filename = $_;
      #print "$filename\n";
        if  (-f $filename) {
          if ($filename =~ /GDS/) {
        print "Found the file in $File::Find::dir/$_\n";
       #return unless -f;
       #return unless /\.source$/;
      push (@files_list, $filename);
       print "$filename\n";
By this logic it is able to trace all the files and follow them and print them